# JavaScript code for my Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a simple gallery page using html and css. I coded this onto a html viewer and it was working fine however when I opened it up in google chrome and IE the onmouseover is not working. When you go over a selected thumbnail, it is supposed to be display a larger image in the bottom box however it does not work.

I posted this question before and got very good replies. I would like to ask if someone can please give me a PLAIN javascript code that I would need to put in to make this work. I have this code that someone kindly gave which works but would like a java script only code if possible.

```
$(function(){
    $('.thumbnails img').hover(function(){
        $('#preview').attr('src',$(this).attr('src'));
    },null);
});
```

Thank you all!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
<title>Gallery</title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
background: #222;
margin-top: 100px;
}

h3 {
color: #eee;
font-family: Verdana;
}

.thumbnails img {
height: 100px;
border: 4px solid #555;
padding: 1px;
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.thumbnails img:hover {
border: 4px solid #00ccff;
cursor:pointer;
}

.preview img {
border: 4px solid #444;
padding: 1px;
width: 800px;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>


<div class="gallery" align="center">


<div class="thumbnails">
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img1.src" id="img1" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2qjj62b.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img2.src" id="img2" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/mb4c21.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img3.src" id="img3" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/35avvpw.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img4.src" id="img4" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/29qnjme.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img5.src" id="img5" src="http://i62.tinypic.com/zkmvd2.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img6.src" id="img6" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/oqezus.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img7.src" id="img7" src="http://i57.tinypic.com/1tx6oj.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>  
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img8.src" id="img8" src="http://i58.tinypic.com/143onsj.jpg" alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img9.src" id="img9" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/2l16qf.jpg"  alt="Image Not Loaded"/>
    <img onmouseover="preview.src=img0.src" id="img0" src="http://i61.tinypic.com/21l0own.jpg"  alt="Image Not Loaded"/>

</div></br>

<div class="preview" align="center">
    <img id="preview" src="http://i60.tinypic.com/2qjj62b.jpg" alt="No Image Loaded"/>
</div>

</br>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with it on Chrome/Linux: http://jsfiddle.net/2AM2N/... Ah, just saw you want plain JS version, right?

Comment: Yes please, just a plain javascript :)

Comment: Sure, give me a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the vanilla JS version of your gallery:

```
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnails')[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onmouseover = function () {
        document.getElementById('preview').src = this.src;
    }
}
```

See it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/2AM2N/5/

---

UPDATE

Here's how to use descriptions from alt attributes:

```
document.getElementById('desc').innerHTML = this.alt; // this goes inside our loop
```

Here is the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/2AM2N/6/

Comment: No problem! :) You might want to use it combined with image.onload in case you're using some slow and big images, but yeah, this should get you started.

Comment: @user3449976 if the answer really gives you what you need, then kindly mark it as a correct answer to others can benefit from it.

Comment: Thank you and will do! Thank you again so much. One more question, you don't have to reply if you don't want to but what if i was thinking of putting a description under each enlarged image, How would I do that? So if i wanted to have different descriptions underneath the enlarged images.

Comment: You're welcome! :)  Well, the most natural approach seem to be using the alt attribute, but you can store the descriptions elsewhere. I'll show you how to use it with alt, and then you can replicate that to whatever you want. Give me a min.